# Why is Google Chrome less precise with element placement?

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering, cross-browser

For example, if I make a block of four images that are absolutely positioned with 50% width and 50% height, the result in Internet Explorer looks like this:
http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/8376/96774641.png
The images are placed right next to each-other, as would be expected.

But the same code in Chrome produces this:
http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/7976/chrome.png
The images are shrunken slightely to make room for the spacing in-between.

My styles already include:

```
border-style: none;
border-width: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

... so why is Chrome spacing my images apart from each-other, and how can I fix it without altering the display for other browsers that render correctly in the first place?

**EDIT:** `<link removed>`
Be aware that the actual page is much more complicated, with over 1,000 `<img>` elements.
It will load slowly in any browser that is not hardware accelerated.
I have confirmed that FireFox renders it identically to IE8, with the images next to each-other as they should be.

Comment: A test page and behaviors on Firefox?

Comment: Yes please. What @SHiNKiROU says

Comment: Are you seriously placing thousands of elements using three-decimals percentage values? No surprise there are some discrepancies between browsers...

Comment: @Agos: I know, right? I'm attempting a practically impossible and ridiculous feat. But it already functions in IE and FireFox, and if I can get it to work in Chrome it'll be roughly complete. As for the thousands of elements, that becomes a moot point as soon as you have a hardware-accelerated browser like Chrome or IE9.

Comment: @Giffyguy I'm sure you have your reasons to do it this way, but have you considered making a dynamic JS request to a resizing script that serves a resized `background-image`?

Comment: @Pekka: When all is said and done, this will not be a repeating image whatsoever. Each image will have a dynamically set `src` and will load a seperate image from it's neighbors.

Comment: @Pekka ~ I foresee a civ clone in the works here. You?

Comment: @drachenstern I'm afraid I'm a total games analphabet, so I can't really comment! :) But well possible. The last game I played excessively was Duke Nukem 3D in 1997. Using printer cables to play over the network...

Comment: @Pekka ~ oh wow, talk about nostalgia `:p` ... ever play Marathon on Apple computers back then? That was our poison at the time `:D`

Comment: @drachenstern nope, we all had PCs, there were rarely any Apples around back then. Not the healthiest of times but fun! And great games, from before games became the huge industry they are today.

Comment: @Giffyguy I guess Safari's placement is off too? How about Opera? It would be really interesting to know which browser(s) is(are) “doing it right”. Are IE/FF always `floor`ing? Is this really more correct? All I can say is, I understand your sub-pixel woes.

Comment: @agos I agree with your comment "is this really more correct?" because there's not really much of a spec here is there? Is this covered by the W3C spec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be a rounding issue: A width of `50%` may well end up as `223.5px` for example.

Seeing as you're using images with a fixed size, why not specify the positions in pixels as well?

Comment: I provided a link to the HTML page I am working on. Let me know if you'd like any further information.

Comment: Also, I appreciate the advice regarding setting a fixed size in pixels for the images. However, I am going for an extremely dynamic environment, and hard-coding pixel sizes really works against that. The dynamic sizing works flawlessly in IE and FireFox, and I'd like to bend Chrome to this mentality before I resort to hard-coding anything like that.

Comment: @Giffyguy I see. That makes it more tricky. So the image sizes are relative as well and have widths of 50%? (can't open the linked page right now)

Comment: They are. Actually, the images I am testing with are only 16x16 pixels. They are enlarged in my current test to about 28-29 pixels.

Comment: @giffyguy ~ Pictures and other widths tend to come in conveniently integer sized pieces. Having 28.4 and 28.6 as picture and placeholder widths would evaluate to a 1px difference. 28.5 and 28.5 would be iffy. You really need to set to a specific value after calculating for fluid dynamics.

Comment: @drachenstern: Where are you seeing 28.4 and 28.6? Those numbers sound significant based on my previous calculations, and I'd like to see where you are pulling them from.

Comment: @Giffygui I'm seeing values like 42.727% in Chrome's element inspector

Comment: @Pekka: That is correct. This is a high-precision rendering experiment, testing the hardware accelerated browsers for usability in more complex rendering projects.

Comment: @Giffyguy interestingly, this took 20-30 seconds to render in Chrome the first time on my 8GB, 3GhZ quad-core workstation with mid-range graphics card - definitely too long to be usable. It renders lightning fast now though - not sure what the bottleneck is / was

Comment: @Pekka: Good to know. I assume you are using Chrome in this instance. I am already planning on the initial loading being slow, and I can deal with that. Also, my server is a single core AMD from five years ago with 8GB RAM and a Comcast Business Internet connection, so loading will never be ideal at this point.

Comment: @Giffyguy yup, it's Chrome. As said, works fine now even after a browser restart

Comment: @giffyguy I'm not, I was using an example. Sorry that I didn't take YOUR EXACT EXAMPLE as my canonical example, and that I wanted to illustrate a point. (In this case note that the browser only gives me integer sizes for pictures so I can't determine if it actually tried to make a fractionally larger size before displaying it) Additionally note that in Chrome when I resize the window narrower from max on my screen I see that some elements join up to each other.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a rounding issue sure enough. Not sure what can be done about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. This has been informative. I'll see what I can do from here.

Comment: Related note: I had just upgraded to Chrome Beta 8 and activated GPU rendering - it was very fast!

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a CSS reset?  Browser default styles can cause irritating problems like paragraphs with differnt top margin heights or other quirks of layout.  This particular case may not be fixed with a CSS reset, but it would eliminate the possibility.

Sadly, the CSS3 option to set a background image scale is not yet available in any reliable way, or you could set the image as a repeating background image scaled to 50%, which of course would have no gaps.  That won't be an optin for quite some time, most likely.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the **Inspector** (right-click on the image, select **Inspect element**) to trace where that spacing is coming from?

Comment: @Giffyguy you really didn't answer his question. You could narrow it down further by inspecting the live calculated values of the CSS and the image by the browser. That's why the developer tools provide those tools.

Comment: I have looked through the Chrome element inspection interface, and haven't seen anything noteworthy that would indicate the cause of the problem.